# Write Spark Dataframe to PosgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, jdbc

I'm trying to write a Spark Dataframe to a pre-created PostgreSQL table. I get the following error during the INSERT process of my job :

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO ref.tableA(a,b) VALUES ('Mike',548758) was aborted. Call getNextException to see the cause.
```

I also tried to catch the error and call the getNextException method but i still have the same error in the logs. In order to write the Dataframe to the corresponding table i used the following process :

```
val jdbcProps = new java.util.Properties()
jdbcProps.setProperty("driver", Config.psqlDriver)
jdbcProps.setProperty("user", Config.psqlUser)
jdbcProps.setProperty("password", Config.psqlPassword)
jdbcProps.setProperty("stringtype", "unspecified")

df.write
  .format("jdbc")
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .jdbc(Config.psqlUrl, tableName, jdbcProps)
```

Package versions :
 - Spark : 1.6.2
 - Scala : 2.10.6

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are there any additional stacks in the causal chain if you look at the full logs as gathered by `yarn logs` ?

Comment: there is no problem in the code so you just have to confirm if the url or tableName or username and password matches or not

Comment: The issue is due to a non-matching type between the Spark sql types and the PostgreSQL types.
There is no more informations in the logs.

Comment: How do you know there's a type mismatch if there's no more info in the logs? Why did you add the `stringtype` line to `jdbcProps`? It's possible that may be the cause... I have never had to add such a line to write a Spark `DataFrame` to Postgres...